# How to write in more pythonic way?

Tags: python

I want to write this code in more pythonic way. Have you any idea how I can do this?

```
def counter():
    for x in self.get_xs():
        total_x = 0
        result = (re.sub('[^0-9]', '', x))
        for number in result:
            total_x += int(number)
        yield(total_x)
```

Comment: Where is the result from ?

Comment: Where did `result` came from? Perhaps you meant: `re.sub('[^0-9]', '', x)`.

Comment: Yes, sorry for mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the sum using [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and a generator expression. If the iterable passed to `sum()` is empty(i.e `re.sub()` returned `''`) then it will simply return the default `start` value 0.

```
def counter():
    r = re.compile('[^0-9]')
    for x in self.get_xs():
        yield sum(int(number) for number in r.sub('', x))
```

In Python 3.3+ you can use `yield from`:

```
def counter():
    r = re.compile('[^0-9]')
    yield from (sum(map(int, r.sub('', x))) for x in self.get_xs())
```

Comment: I think, in this case, where there's just one `yield from`, you could also do `return (<generator>)` in Python 2.

Comment: It would be a good idea to move the compiled regular expression out of the function so it’s reused instead of recompiled every time. Also, the function likely needs a `self` argument.

Comment: @poke IIRC Python caches regular expressions.

Comment: The docs say: "The compiled versions of the most recent patterns passed to re.match(), re.search() or re.compile() are cached, so programs that use only a few regular expressions at a time needn’t worry about compiling regular expressions." `re.sub` is not mentioned.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Interesting, I didn’t know that!

Comment: @Matthias But I am using `re.compile` first.